# Rspec rails routes Error parameter missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
RSpec.describe 'Book', :type => :request do
  describe 'List Books' do
    let(:book) { FactoryGirl.create :book }
    before(:each) do
      visit root_path
    end
    context 'when book is created' do
      let(:book) { FactoryGirl.create :book, title: 'My Book Title' }
      it 'should list books' do
        post books_path({book: book})        
        expect(page).to have_content 'My Book Title'
      end
    end
    context 'when no book is created' do
      it 'should not list books' do
        expect(page).to have_content 'No books found'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Failure/Error: params.require(:book).permit(:title, :abstract, :author, :pages, :price, :image_file_name, :genre, :published_on)

```
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: book
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RSpec.describe 'Book', :type => :request do
  describe 'List Books' do
    let(:book) { FactoryGirl.create :book }
    before(:each) do
      visit root_path
    end
    context 'when book is created' do
      let(:book) { FactoryGirl.create :book, title: 'My Book Title' }
      it 'should list books' do
        post books_path({book: book})
        #visit root_path(book)
        #expect(page).to have_content 'Displaying 1 book'
        expect(page).to have_content 'No books found'
      end
    end
    context 'when no book is created' do
      it 'should not list books' do
        expect(page).to have_content 'No books found'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your controller you can change

```
params.require(:book).permit(:title, :abstract, :author, :pages, :price, :image_file_name, :genre, :published_on)
```

to

```
params.require(:book)
params.permit(:title, :abstract, :author, :pages, :price, :image_file_name, :genre, :published_on)
```

The issue is that you are saying I want to permit these values to be passed into the book parameter. Unless book is a hash like the `{book => {'title' => 'Cat and the Hat', 'auther' => 'Me'}}` the permit method won't work correctly on it. So either change the structure of your params, or white list them in two steps

Comment: it shows   undefined method `permit' for "424":String

Comment: it is redirecting it to book details page not to list books

Comment: Can you add your controller

Comment: No just have to crate book

Comment: I mean can you add the controller code to the question

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by `post books_path(book)`.
The correct implementation is:

```
RSpec.describe 'Book', :type => :request do
  describe 'List Books' do
    let(:book) { FactoryGirl.create :book }
    before(:each) do
      visit root_path
    end
    context 'when book is created' do
      let!(:book) { FactoryGirl.create :book, title: 'My Book Title' }
      it 'should list books' do
        expect(page).to have_content 'Displaying 1 book'
        expect(page).not_to have_content 'No books found'
      end
    end
    context 'when no book is created' do
      it 'should not list books' do
        expect(page).to have_content 'No books found'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it is redirecting it to book details page not to list books

Comment: What is the root_path in your specs? The point is to create book without hitting controller by calling `let!(:book)`. In your current implementation it is not quiet clear what are you testing: post action, redirection after book creation or index view.

Comment: create book and see if it is listed at index, root_path is pointing at index page that lists book

Comment: Ok, than my approach will work for you. Use `let!` to create book, than `visit root_path`. Created book should be visible. Tested on scaffold'ed rails 5 project.

Answer (score 0):

In the below example i am using Let to create an instance variable. Using let the variable lazy loads only when it is used the first time in the test and get cached until that specific test is finished.
therefore i will have book instance created for one example and no books created for anther example to test

```
RSpec.describe 'Book', :type => :request do
  describe 'List Books' do
    before(:each) do
      visit books_path
    end
    context 'when book is created' do
      let!(:book) { FactoryGirl.create :book, title: 'My Book Title' }
      it 'should list books' do
        expect(page).to have_content 'Displaying all 2   book'
        expect(page).to have_content 'My Book Title'
      end
    end
    context 'when no book is created' do
      it 'should not list books' do
        expect(page).to have_content 'No books found'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

does this test full fills the need to test list of book